# Application crash when i run it in a real device iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

I am developing an application when using networking with Alamofire on Xcode 8.3 and when i used Alamofire code in the simulator it's working but when i tried my code in a real device iPhone 7 which has 10.2 iOS Version the application stop and getting

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and this break point exception

```
libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, file : Swift.StaticString, line : Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never:
    0x101b003d0 <+0>:   stp    x26, x25, [sp, #-0x50]!
    0x101b003d4 <+4>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #0x10]
    0x101b003d8 <+8>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x20]
    0x101b003dc <+12>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x30]
    0x101b003e0 <+16>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x40]
    0x101b003e4 <+20>:  add    x29, sp, #0x40            ; =0x40 
    0x101b003e8 <+24>:  mov    x19, x6
    0x101b003ec <+28>:  mov    x20, x5
    0x101b003f0 <+32>:  mov    x21, x4
    0x101b003f4 <+36>:  mov    x22, x3
    0x101b003f8 <+40>:  mov    x23, x2
    0x101b003fc <+44>:  mov    x24, x1
    0x101b00400 <+48>:  mov    x25, x0
    0x101b00404 <+52>:  adr    x8, #0xf11fc              ; protocol descriptor for Swift._DefaultCustomPlaygroundQuickLookable + 136
    0x101b00408 <+56>:  nop    
    0x101b0040c <+60>:  add    x0, x8, #0x10             ; =0x10 
    0x101b00410 <+64>:  mov    w1, #0x28
    0x101b00414 <+68>:  orr    w2, wzr, #0x7
    0x101b00418 <+72>:  bl     0x101b00750               ; swift_rt_swift_allocObject
    0x101b0041c <+76>:  mov    x8, x0
    0x101b00420 <+80>:  stp    x22, x21, [x8, #0x10]
    0x101b00424 <+84>:  strb   w20, [x8, #0x20]
    0x101b00428 <+88>:  str    w19, [x8, #0x24]
    0x101b0042c <+92>:  adr    x3, #0x40440              ; partial apply forwarder for Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, file : Swift.StaticString, line : Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never).(closure #2)
    0x101b00430 <+96>:  nop    
    0x101b00434 <+100>: mov    x0, x25
    0x101b00438 <+104>: mov    x1, x24
    0x101b0043c <+108>: mov    x2, x23
    0x101b00440 <+112>: mov    x4, x8
    0x101b00444 <+116>: bl     0x1019e14dc               ; function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[1] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> ()]> of generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A> ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
->  0x101b00448 <+120>: brk    #0x1
```

and this is my code which i run

```
Alamofire.request(APIKeys().login, method: .post, parameters: ["email" : email , "password"  : password ], encoding: JSONEncoding.default , headers: APIKeys().headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: {( response  ) in
            if response.result.value != nil {
                print(response)
             let json = JSON(response.result.value ?? "")
            if json["status"].intValue  == 200
            {
                UserDefaults().set(json["email"].stringValue, forKey: "email")
                UserDefaults().set(json["id"].intValue, forKey: "userID")


            }


            }


        } )
```

Comment: I would guess one of our IBOutlets isn't connected.  Check them all.

Comment: All outlets connected

Comment: Are you sure that this peace of code is creating a problem .. I don't think so, You are actually wrapping some optional value which contains nil ..

Comment: When i comment this peace of code its didn't get that error

Comment: Are you sure the phone is connected to the Internet?

Comment: Did you nuke caches and clean derived data? I noticed `Swift._DefaultCustomPlaygroundQuickLookable` in there.

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and determine the line causing the exception or if you have already done this, look back through the stack trace to find the code where the exception was thrown.

Comment: Check Your device version and simulator version that you run.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed Its connected to the internet

Comment: @Adrian maybe i need to uninstall my app and try again ?

Comment: @ashwini my development target 10.0 and the device 10.2

Comment: what is output of print(response) statement ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Cleaned the cache and reinstalled the app and it's working well at the device